# Get the current face value of flip Clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

```js
  var clock;


       // Instantiate a counter
      clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
        autoStart: false,
        countdown: true
      });
      var time = clock.getFaceValue();
```

How do you get the current face value of the flip clock, as it continuously countdown. I've tried using getTime() and a number of different functions that are defined in their java script file. I don't understand how to achieve this.

Comment: Can I atleast get some feedback? I'm not asking for the answer here. I'm honestly confused

Comment: var time  = clock.getFaceValue();

Comment: @XTOTHEL 
"clock.getFaceValue is not a function" this is what I get, all the time.

Comment: Can you paste in your code for initialization of flipclock? the "clock" is the name of the flipclock that you've defined.

Comment: @XTOTHEL I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {

  clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 10, {
    clockFace: 'Counter',
    autoStart: true,
    countdown: true,
    callbacks: {
      interval: function() {
        var time = this.factory.getTime().time;

        if (time) {
          console.log(time);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: I get "Unexpected identifier" when I try this. It's beyond me at this point.

Comment: Yeah, still does not output the faceValue, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the time/counter value. If you are querying outside of the callbacks, then simply:

```
clock.getTime().time
```

Try it out in the browser console first. The documentation in this part is really confusing. I guess this plugin hasn't been updated since 5 years ago.